# Is there a way to include the namespace inside a value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have got several namespaces (iso, dev, sandbox, etc.) which correspond to my different environments. For each environment and thus namespace, there is an associated db.
When I deploy my pod with Helm, I would like to inject the namespace inside a value to get the appropriate password .

In my values file I have something that looks like this :

```
db:
  iso: passwordISO
  dev: passwordDEV
  sandbox: passwordSANDBOX
  spec: passwordSPEC
  val: passwordVAL
```

and in my consumer_config file I have this :

```
  db_host: DB_HOST-{{ .Release.Namespace }}
  db_port: DB_PORT
  db_name: DB_NAME
  db_user: DB_PORT
  db_password: {{ .Values.db.iso }}
```

I already tried to use the `{{- include }}` pattern but with no success. I also tried `{{ .Values.db.{{ .Release.Namespace }}}}` giving me the following error `unexpected <.> in operand`

Any insight on how to do this or any workaround ?

Comment: It is not advisable to store BD passwords inside helm values.yaml file. instead create a secret object containing DB passwords in their respective namspaces and attach them to the pods.

Answer (score 1):

As Helm is based on the Go-template language, the functions availabe in the go-template language can be of help:

```
{{ index .Values.db .Release.Namespace }}
```

From the docs (go-template docs):

> index
>       Returns the result of indexing its first argument by the
>       following arguments. Thus "index x 1 2 3" is, in Go syntax,
>       x[1][2][3]. Each indexed item must be a map, slice, or array.

so in this case you index `.Values.db` with the key `.Release.Namespace`